# Windows phone 8 - Include XAML in another XAML file

Tags: xaml

im currently developping a windows phone application and i was wondering if it was possible to include another XAML file in a XAML file.

I've heard about UserControl but im not really sure how I should use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mechanisms that may provide the functionality you're looking for:

1. Subclassing 
   XAML pages can be subclassed. For example: 
   [xaml.cs (for subclass)] 
   `public partial class SubclassPage : BasePage` 
   [xaml (for subclass)] 
   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` 
   `<BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"` 
   `...` 
   `>` 
   etc.
2. User control 
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh144799(v=vs.100).aspx 
   (skip to the section "Adding a new user control to the project")

Bottom Line: 
If you want to include a XAML file in another because 2 pages are very similar, consider subclassing. 
 Alternatively, if you find the same collection of elements is reused across multiple pages (perhaps copy-pasted), strongly consider refactoring it into a user control.